# Is there a way I can loop an input until dsquery is successful?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, active-directory

I'm trying to figure out a way for my batch file to repeat a question if the dsget is unsuccessful.

This is what I currently have:

```
@echo off
set /p input="Enter AD Username to lookup: "
dsquery user -samid %input% |dsget user -memberof |dsget group -samid |find /v "samid"|findstr /v "dsget%" | clip | echo User found & echo.Groups copied to clipboard
pause
```

It copies a users active directory groups to the clipboard, but if its unsuccessful you have to reopen the batch file, which I don't want to happen.

Basically if the dsquery is unsuccessful in finding a user i want it to say something like

```
User not found
Enter an AD Username to lookup:
```

and only if its successful it will clip the contents of the dsquery

Answer (score 0):

I do not have dsquery or dsget so I can not test this.

See [one-line conditional execution in windows1](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php).
[one-line conditional execution in windows2](https://www.google.com/search?q=one-line%20conditional%20execution%20in%20windows&ie=&oe=)

```
command1 && command2 || command3
```

Execute command2 only if command1 is successful. Execute command3 if command1 fails.

[if %errorlevel% neq 0](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)

```
@echo off
:loop 
set /p input="Enter AD Username to lookup: "
REM Since I can't test it this is a 51/49 guess
REM MAYBE?
dsquery user -samid %input% | dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid  | FIND /i "dsget failed" > NUL && goto :loop || clip
REM dsquery user -samid %input% | dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid | FINDSTR /i /c:"dsget failed">NUL | clip
REM IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto :loop
echo User found. Groups copied to clipboard.
pause 
exit
```

Comment: Unfortunately that command is still parsed regardless if the user exists or not. Do you know how I would be able to a findstr conditional to counteract this? Like IF [the result of dsquery] has the string [dsget failed] then goto loop?

Comment: I don't have dsquery so I can't test anything I give you.    `| dsget  group -samid | FINDSTR /i /n /c:"dsget failed">NUL` && goto :loop

Comment: The construct `findstr /v "dsget%" && | clip || goto :loop
echo User found. Groups copied to clipboard.` cannot work, it's wrong syntax. Any `&&`/`||` react on the exit code of the previous command, which is not the same as the `ErrorLevel` value; so I believe here it would be better to have `if not ErrorLevel 1 goto :loop` after the `dsquery` line...

Comment: @aschipfl Is this wrong?  `if errorlevel 1 echo Previous command most likely exited with an error code.`

`if not errorlevel 1 echo Previous command most likely finished successfully.`

Comment: This seems to be correct. Note that `if ErrorLevel 1` actually means *if `ErrorLevel` is greater than or equal to `1`* and `if not ErrorLevel 1` means *if `ErrorLevel` is less than `1`*, so negative values (although rare) could be treated wrongly. Anyway, I don't know if `dsquery` modifies `ErrorLevel` and how...

Comment: @aschipfl. I appreciate that you don't use dsquery. How does the && / || look to you? I want it to go to the loop if it finds "dsget failed": `dsquery user -samid %input% | dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid | FIND /i "dsget failed" > NUL && goto :loop || clip`

Comment: I can't try it either.  I don't have dsquery or dsget.